# Eclipse (Code Composer Studio) - Preprocessor Macros not shown after 5000 lines of code?

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm using the Code Composer Studio from Texas Instruments for a microcontroller application. This is an eclipse based environment. Now there is a file, which has more than 5000 lines of code and it does not show the precompiler macros (the #if/#else case is can not be distinguished, because the background is white for both). When I reduce the code to less than 5000 lines, it shows everything correctly.

So, is there a setting somehwere, where I can choose the maximum number of lines before it compresses? (I had a question once when I open a large file about that, but now it never shows it again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting is "scalability": Window-> Preferences->C/C++-> Editor->Scalability.

There are checkboxes for things to disable in large files (live parsing, syntax coloring etc) and how large a file must be to trigger these limitations. The default usually is 5000 lines.

Comment: Why would anyone ever want to disable syntax coloring? It's not like it's CPU intense for the IDE.

Comment: It takes processing resources & memory, and can slow the IDE down on huge files, not ideal for live editing session. There are slow or memory limited systems, like emulators, VMs..

Comment: @ddbug The only IDE I've ever seen slow down is Eclipse. I've used some 50+ other programming IDEs that never had such problems.